# !Clipper library Line polygon use offset How it Union

Tags: polygon, offset, clipperlib

I want Draw Line polygon and Use Offset But it Union[image]

Answer (score 2):

Suppadech, I suggest you pass two closed paths the the ClipperOffset object where the second path is oriented in the opposite direction to the first.

```
  int main()
  {
    Paths subj(2);
    Paths solution;
    subj[0] << IntPoint(10,10) << IntPoint(100,10) << IntPoint(100,100) <<  IntPoint(10,100);
    subj[1] << IntPoint(10,10) << IntPoint(10,100) << IntPoint(100,100) <<  IntPoint(100,10);
    ClipperOffset co;
    co.AddPaths(subj, jtSquare, etClosedPolygon);
    co.Execute(solution, 5.0);
  }
```